# Why is my sql script returning "[null]" and "0" values even though my table is populated?

Tags: sql, select, null

I have manually populated a table as follows:

```
INSERT INTO country  VALUES
-- columns are countryid, name, continent, population, gdp, lifeexpectancy, founded
(1, 'Argentina', 36.3, 348.2, 70.75, 9/7/1816), 
(2, 'Brazil', 183.3, 1004, 65.6, 9/7/1822),
(3, 'Canada', 30.1, 658, 77.08, 1/7/1867),
(4, 'England', 60.8, 1256, 75.15, NULL),
(5, 'France', 60, 1000, 75.15, 14/7/1789),
(6, 'Mexico', 107.5, 694.3, 69.36, 16/9/1821),
(7, 'USA', 270, 8003, 75.75, 4/7/1776),
(8, 'Cuba', 11.7, 16.9, 75.95, 24/2/1895),
(9, 'Guatemala', 20, 200, 60, 15/9/1821),
(10, 'Tanzania', 55.57, 47.43, 60.76, 9/12/1961),
(11, 'India', 1324, 2264, 68.35, NULL),
(12, 'South Africa', 55.91, 294.8, 57.44, 31/05/1910),
(13, 'Costa Rica', 4.86, 57.44, 79.59, 15/9/1821),
(14, 'Uganda', 41.49, 25.53, 59.18, NULL);
```

but when I query

```
SELECT lifeexpectancy FROM country;
```

The tables returns a combination of "0" and "[null]" values.

I've tried changing the data_type of lifeexpectancy. Neither text nor numeric data types return values that have been entered.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I can see a couple of problems: 1) You say your table has 7 columns, but your insert statement only has 6 columns, 2) you aren't delimiting the date values on the insert, 3) you aren't stipulating the column order of the insert statement. It would help if you could post the output of the following query: `SELECT * FROM country`

Comment: Which database? If oracle then you have to `commit` after insert.

Comment: In addition to what e_i_pi wrote: 4) you are not providing the dates as proper date literals (in standard SQL you could use e.g. `date '186-07-09'`)

Comment: You really ought to get in the habit of specifying the columns to insert into in your `INSERT` statement, not just as a comment but as part of the syntax.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're supplying 6 values instead of 7 (may be because of Auto Increment), if that the case you need to specify the columns here.

Also pass date with single quotes surrounded:

```
INSERT INTO country (countryid, name, continent, population, gdp, lifeexpectancy, founded) 
VALUES 
(1, 'Argentina', 36.3, 348.2, 70.75, '9/7/1816'), 
(2, 'Brazil', 183.3, 1004, 65.6, '9/7/1822'),
(3, 'Canada', 30.1, 658, 77.08, '1/7/1867'),
(4, 'England', 60.8, 1256, 75.15, NULL),
(5, 'France', 60, 1000, 75.15, '14/7/1789'),
(6, 'Mexico', 107.5, 694.3, 69.36, '16/9/1821'),
(7, 'USA', 270, 8003, 75.75, '4/7/1776'),
(8, 'Cuba', 11.7, 16.9, 75.95, '24/2/1895'),
(9, 'Guatemala', 20, 200, 60, '15/9/1821'),
(10, 'Tanzania', 55.57, 47.43, 60.76, '9/12/1961'),
(11, 'India', 1324, 2264, 68.35, NULL),
(12, 'South Africa', 55.91, 294.8, 57.44, '31/05/1910'),
(13, 'Costa Rica', 4.86, 57.44, 79.59, '15/9/1821'),
(14, 'Uganda', 41.49, 25.53, 59.18, NULL);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not inserting the continent.  Presumably you want that, but it is not in your sample data.

You should be using standard date formats.  In most databases, YYYY-MM-DD works.  And you should list the columns.  So:

```
INSERT INTO country (countryid, name, population, gdp, lifeexpectancy, founded) 
    VALUES (1, 'Argentina', 36.3, 348.2, 70.75, '1816-07-09'), 
           (2, 'Brazil', 183.3, 1004, 65.6, '1822-07-09'),
           (3, 'Canada', 30.1, 658, 77.08, '1867-07-01'),
           (4, 'England', 60.8, 1256, 75.15, NULL),
           (5, 'France', 60, 1000, 75.15, '1789-07-14'),
           (6, 'Mexico', 107.5, 694.3, 69.36, '1821-09-16'),
           (7, 'USA', 270, 8003, 75.75, '1776-07-04'),
           (8, 'Cuba', 11.7, 16.9, 75.95, '1895-02-24'),
           (9, 'Guatemala', 20, 200, 60, '1821-09-15'),
           (10, 'Tanzania', 55.57, 47.43, 60.76, '1961-12-09'),
           (11, 'India', 1324, 2264, 68.35, NULL),
           (12, 'South Africa', 55.91, 294.8, 57.44, '1910-05-31'),
           (13, 'Costa Rica', 4.86, 57.44, 79.59, '1821-09-15'),
           (14, 'Uganda', 41.49, 25.53, 59.18, NULL);
```